# About $\log (1 + x)$ on p.427 "Calculus 4th Edtion" by Michael Spivak

Tags: calculus, analysis, logarithms, taylor-expansion, proof-explanation

I am reading "Calculus 4th Edtion" by Michael Spivak.

On p.427 he wrote as follows:

> From the calculations on page 413, we see that for $x \geq 0$ we have
>   $$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}t^{n+1}$$ where $$\left \vert {\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} t^{n+1}}\right\vert \leq \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ and there is a slightly more complicated estimate when $-1 < x < 0$ (Problem 16).

I guess $t \in (0, x)$ if $x > 0$ and $t = 0$ if $x = 0$.

Does the above equality really hold?

I guess Spivak applied Taylor's theorem(p.424, Lagrange form of the remainder) incorrectly to $\log(1 + x)$.

Comment: Do you mean the formula for $\ln(1+x)$?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: Well, that's Maclaurin formula at order $n$ for $\ln(1+x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, what Spivak writes is that$$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}n+\int_0^x\frac{t^n}{t+1}\,\mathrm dt.$$But then$$x\geqslant0\implies\int_0^x\frac{t^n}{t+1}\,\mathrm dt\leqslant\int_0^xt^n\,\mathrm dt=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}.$$

Comment: Did You derive the above equality from $1-x+x^2-\cdots+(-1)^n x^n = \frac{1-(-x)^{n+1}}{1+x}$?

Comment: By the way, on p.413, Spivak calculates $f^{(k)} (0) = (-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!$, where $f(x) = \log(1+x)$.

Comment: I guess Spivak applied Taylor's theorem(p.424) incorrectly to $\ln(1+x)$.

Comment: Spivak applied to $\log(1+x)$ the integral form of the remainder:$$R_{n,a}(x)=\int_a^x\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^n\,\mathrm dt,$$with $a=0$.

Comment: How can we derive $\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}t^{n+1}$ from $R_{n,a}(x)$?

Comment: That equality makes no sense to me and I can't find it in Spivak's *Calculus*. I have a copy of the third edition before my eyes.

Comment: I checked 3rd Edition now. In 3rd Edition, the equality "$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}t^{n+1}$" does not exist.

Comment: In only 4th edition, the equality $\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}t^{n+1}$ exists.

Comment: Now I understand your answer. Thank you very much for your answer.