# Prove for $x\ge 0,\log(1+x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{i}x^{i}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}z^{n+1}$ for some $z\lt x$.

Tags: calculus, logarithms, taylor-expansion

In Spivak, it says, for $x\ge 0,\log(1+x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{i}x^{i}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}z^{n+1}$ for some $z\lt x$.

My attempt:
I agree with the first part of the sum, since it is the n-th degree Taylor polynomial at $0$.  But why is the remainder term of the form $\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}z^{n+1}$?  I thought the lagrange remainder term was of the form $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}$.  So then since $f(x)=\log(1+x)$, then the n+1 derivative is $f^{(n+1)}(x)=(-1)^{n}n!(1+x)^{-(n+1)}$, so the lagrange remainder term should be $f^{(n+1)}(t)=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+1}(1+t)^{-(n+1)}$, but this takes us nowhere.

Alternatively, I know $\log(1+x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{1+t}\,dt$ and also $\frac{1}{1+t}=\frac{t^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1}}{1+t}+\sum_{i=0}^{n}t^{i}(-1)^i$, so we can get an alternative formula for $\log(1+x)$, namely $$\log(1+x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i \,\frac{x^{i+1}}{i+1} \, +(-1)^{n+1}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^{n+1}}{1+t}dt$$ which is almost in the desired form, I just need to show the final integral part can be written as $\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}z^{n+1}$ for some $z$.  I sense I am close but I am unable to explain why  $x\ge 0,\log(1+x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{i}x^{i}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}z^{n+1}$ for some $z$

Comment: The Taylor expansion only works for $-1<x<1$ I'm not sure if it helps but you probably need to keep it in mind.  Are you really to prove it for all $x$?

Comment: Why is it only valid for $-1 \lt x \lt 1$ ?

Comment: It's a basic fact about Taylor Series.  Because $\log(1-x)$ is not defined when $x=1$ and (up to endpoints) the interval of convergence is symmetric about the origin.

Comment: Right.  I just wanted to understand where Spivak got the final part $\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+1}z^{n+1}$.  Similar question was asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251868/about-log-1-x-on-p-427-calculus-4th-edtion-by-michael-spivak?rq=1 but was also unanswered.

Comment: I understand your question I just think it may not be true for all $x$.  If it is true for all $x$ then you can't use the Taylor series argument.  For $|x|<1$ I tried to use the Taylor and solve for $z$ and I get an inequality which can't hold true so that makes me suspect this is not actually true as stated.

Comment: I see, thank you for time!

Comment: I may have made a mistake here but consider $n=1$.  The condition then becomes $\log(1+x)=x-\frac12z^2$ for some $z<x$.  Thus $z=\sqrt{2\log(1+x)+2x}$ so since $z<x$ this means $\sqrt{2\log(1+x)+2x}<x$ which means $\log(1+x)+x<\frac12x^2$ which I think, by graphing both sides is not true.

Comment: Shouldn't $z=\sqrt{-2\log(1+x)+2x}$?

Comment: Yes, check the graphs it may still not hold for all $x$

Comment: Is there something faulty with this explanation?$\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}=\frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{(n+1)(t+1)^{n+1}}$ where $x\gt 0$ is fixed and $0\lt t \lt x \implies 1 \lt t+1 \lt x+1 \implies 1 \lt (t+1)^{n+1} \lt (x+1)^{n+1} \implies x^{n+1} \gt \frac{x^{n+1}}{(t+1)^{n+1}} \gt \frac{x^{n+1}}{(x+1)^{n+1}}$ $\\f(y)=y^{n+1}$ continuous on $[\frac{x}{x+1}, x]$, then there exists a $z \in (\frac{x}{x+1}, x)$ such that $z^{n+1}=\frac{x^{n+1}}{(t+1)^{n+1}}$, so $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}z^{n+1}$